# Overriding onTrimMemory in Application vs Activity

Tags: android

What are the merits and de-merits of overriding the onTrimMemory in an Application vs Activity. The Android documentation looks exactly the same for both Application's and Activity's onTrimMemory and it seem they are both called in background.

If I implements the onTrimMemory in Activity and the app is backgrounded and activities onDestroy is called, can onTrimMemory be called after that?

For the above case, should I put the onTrimMemory in the Application if I do want to trim the cache for the app if the onTrimMemory cant be called on the activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override `onTrimMemory(int)` in `Application` or `Activity` (or any other component) based on **who keeps the memory you want to trim**. The class that is responsible for the memory should do the trimming.

The mechanism of the callback is following: the system calls `Application.onTrimMemory(int)` which then calls the same callback on the app's components. The callback is called everywhere where is should be called (I doubt it will be after `Activity.onDestroy()` - you shouldn't care about such activity any more). Your decision to override shouldn't be affected by the Activity lifecycle.

If the memory belongs to the application, handle it there. If it belongs solely to an Activity, handle it there.